# Do AppDynamics python agent supports barebone python scripts w/o wSGI or Gunicorn?

Tags: python-3.x, appdynamics

I have an Extract, Transform, Load (ETL) pipeline that I want to monitor with AppDynamics.

The ignition of the ETL is done via a barebone python command without use of a web server. Hence no WSGI / Gunicorn / uvloop. Is it still possible to monitor the pipelines via appDynamics.

I have gone through [this](https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/python-agent/python-supported-environments) supported environment doc but nothing is specified clearly.

Does anyone have similar experience with AppDynamics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package appdynamics to report ETL as business action.
For more, please refer to this [document](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/21.x/21.3/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/python-agent/python-agent-api/python-agent-api-guide) you'll find detailed examples.

```
from appdynamics.agent import api as appd
# init agent, you can put args in it
appd.init()
# create a handle
bt_handle = appd.start_bt('ETL work')
# ETL to monitor
try:
    do_ETL_work()
except Exception as exc:
    raise
finally:
    appd.end_bt(bt_handle, exc)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the AppDynamics Python Agent "operates from inside the WSGI server that contains the instrumented application." Your use case is not currently supported.

The Python Agent only detects "Python Web" Entry Point Types.

Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/python-agent